# How to format the output of unix shell script flat file which is generated from .sql file in the unix shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, header

I have a unix shell script which extracts the data from the database with a .sql file . In this SQL I need to format the file output with SET commands.  I need the output in such a way that the output display is with the column header without any spacing or lines in the header.

Expected output:

```
Header1,header 2
Mark,California
Steve,India
```

The output I see:(extra line before header and dotted lines after header)

```
Header1, header 2
-----------------
Mark,California
Steve, India
```

Shell script:

```
ABC.sh
a=`sqlplus -silent $Database name @Ggg.sql`
mv xyz.csv xyz_$1.csv
dos2unix xyz_*.csv 2>  /dev/null
 (cat body.txt; uuencode xyz_$1.csv xyz_$1.csv) | mailx -s "subject" 
 name@email.com
(SQL file Gggg.sql is called and email is sent)

Ggg.sql 
`Set pagesize 5000`
`Set linesize 700`
`Set trimspool off`
`Set heading on`
`Set feedback off`
`Set term off`
`Set verify off``
Spool jjj.csv;
`Select * from table1 where column = '5'`;
`SPOOL OFF`;
EXIT`;
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the real shell script you are using, which invokes Ggg.sql . Also specify which database you are using.

Comment: Done, edited. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output contains 5 lines:

```
Header1, header 2
-----------------
Mark,California
Steve, India
```

you can remove the unwanted lines after they are generated using `sed` (or find the way to do in sql which perhaps is harder)

```
ABC.sh | sed '1d;3d'
```

output:

```
Header1, header 2
Mark,California
Steve, India
```

Comment: Perhaps its easier to do it after the output is generated but I need a way to do it in the. SQL file only as the .csv flat file output generated is needed to be in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood about your question, you just want a SQL script to result into your column names followed right after by a table's results, so you could just select the column names and `UNION` them to the table results like this:

```
SELECT 'Header1', 'header 2'
UNION
SELECT Header1, Header2 FROM TableName
```

Reminder that `UNION`'ed selections need to have the same amount of columns.

In case your table schema is more complex than something simple like that, you would need to properly detail it so the query would work as expected.